# Japanese FileName was not show correctly

Tags: javascript, image-uploading

I've uploaded image file with japanese file name to my server from my website and it's return to me as below.(å†™çœŸï¼’.jpg) but the real file was not like that. How should I fix this.

```
Not Found
The requested URL /my_project/uploads/0000000056/å†™çœŸï¼’.jpg 
was not found on this server.
```

Here is my Javascript Code.

```
var filePath = $(ctrl).find(".filePath").val();
var fileName = $(ctrl).find(".fileName").val();
var close = $('#imgPreview').closest("div").find(".filelink");
close.append('<img width=100% height=100% src="{base_url()}'+filePath+fileName+'"></img>');
```

The process is working like that. Upload the image and click on the File Name then File Preview Popup box will appear. But the japanese file name will show as above error message. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Is the page UTF-8 encoded? (just to check)

Comment: Yep I already made it bro.

Comment: (some more Qs) --- What server are you running? Does it support UTF-8 filenames? Can you post the actual text of the filename (for our own testing)?

Comment: My boss said the Server was from Japan. But I don't know it support UTF-8 filenames or not. But i think it'll be support coz of the server was from japan. File name was イルプレビー -.png.

Comment: In the browser console, do you see an error like `GET ../%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%83%BC.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)`? --- Or do you see `å†™çœŸï¼’`?

Comment: Yeah i found like that...

GET .../uploads/0000000056/%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F%EF%BC%92.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144926/discussion-between-evolutionxbox-and-kawazoe-kazuke).